# Calculation of sample space in probability

Tags: probability

$A$ is playing a $9$ match rapid chess tournament against $B$. On average, $A$'s probability of winning a game against $B$ is $0.75$. If $A$ is $3-2$ down after $5$ games, and there are no ties, what is the probability that $A$ will win the championship?

I understand that I need to find the number of matches in which $A$ should win in order to win the championship, i.e., in at least how many matches $A$ should win. However, I do not know how I should calculate it.

I also do not understand the meaning of '$3-2$ down'. Does it mean that in the $5$ matches, $A$ has won $3$ and lost $2$?

Hope someone could explain this to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean A is $2-3$ down ?

Comment: @TitoEliatron If A is down then I would assume B has won more matches so far.  So A needs to win 3 more matches before B wins 2 more, and if matches are independent you can use a binomial distribution with $n=4$ to solve this

Comment: I though the resoult was $A3-2B$. Knowing that $A2-3B$, $A$ must win 3 matches out 4. So 4 posibilities:  AAAo, AABA, ABAA, BAAA.

Comment: The statement that $A$ is $3 - 2$ down means $A$ has won $2$ and lost $3$ matches thus far.  It would have been clearer to say that $B$ is leading $3$ games to $2$.